# Buttons added after page load are not recognized in EventListener

Tags: javascript, css

My `EventListener` isn't targeting elements added after the page initially loads. I originally thought it might have been the order I have it in but I changed where the code is located and tried nesting it within the area the new div is created but it either breaks the color change as a whole or the original issue continues.

My final thought was maybe I need to add an `EventListener` to update the `elems` variable. I was unsuccessful in finding something to guide me.

If you click the original 4 squares they load, but after using the "Add a Square!" button the added divs dont behave the same.

```js
//Turn div red if clicked
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor !== "red") {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#1E1E1E";
  }
}));

//Slider
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var output = document.getElementById("value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  parent.style.width = this.value + "%";
}

//Add Div
function addDiv(parent_div) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var parent = document.getElementById(parent_div);
  if (parent) {
    parent.appendChild(div);
  }
}
var button = document.getElementById("addsquare");
if (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // change dynamically your new div
    addDiv('parent', {
      'class': 'square'
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 94.2%;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parent>div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  width: calc(50px - 2px);
  height: calc(50px - 2px);
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

input,
button {
  margin: 0;
}

.controls {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.controls>h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#addsquare {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slidewrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <h2>Controls</h2>
  <button id="addsquare">Add a Square!</button>
  <div class="slidewrap">
    <input type="range" min="25" max="100" value="25" class="slider" id="range">
    <div>Game zone is set to: <span id="value"></span>%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "My EventListener isn't targeting elements added after the page initially loads"...that's to be expected, the event handler gets added to each selected element when that code runs. So if an element doesn't exist at that moment, then trivially we can see that no event will be attached to it. So basically when you add a new element, you have to attach an event handler to it then. Libraries such as jQuery do provide a mechanism for "delegated" events which give the appearance of listening for events on any element, no matter when added, but you don't seem to be using jQuery here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the event listener to the dynamically created divs:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // change dynamically your new div
  var newDiv = addDiv('parent', { 'class': 'square' });
  newDiv.addEventListener('click', squareClickHandler)
});
```

`squareClickHandler` is just the old anonymous function you used to change the square color.

```js
//Turn div red if clicked
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
Array.from(elems).forEach(v =>
    v.addEventListener('click', squareClickHandler));

function squareClickHandler() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor !== "red") {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#1E1E1E";
  }
}

//Slider
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var output = document.getElementById("value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  parent.style.width = this.value + "%";
}

//Add Div
function addDiv(parent_div) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var parent = document.getElementById(parent_div);
  if (parent) {
    parent.appendChild(div);
  }
  return div;
}
var button = document.getElementById("addsquare");
if (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // change dynamically your new div
    var newDiv = addDiv('parent', {
      'class': 'square'
    });
    
    newDiv.addEventListener('click', squareClickHandler)
  });
}
```

```css
#parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 94.2%;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parent>div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  width: calc(50px - 2px);
  height: calc(50px - 2px);
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

input,
button {
  margin: 0;
}

.controls {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.controls>h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#addsquare {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slidewrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <h2>Controls</h2>
  <button id="addsquare">Add a Square!</button>
  <div class="slidewrap">
    <input type="range" min="25" max="100" value="25" class="slider" id="range">
    <div>Game zone is set to: <span id="value"></span>%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, Thank you! In 9 minutes I can accept your answer. Fast response, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this with event delegation instead of binding the event to each single element. This means you bind the listener to the parent or any other ancestor element and then do what you want to the `event.target` instead.

```js
//Turn div red if clicked
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
parent.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.style.backgroundColor !== "red") {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "#1E1E1E";
  }
});

//Slider
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var output = document.getElementById("value");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;
slider.oninput = function() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  parent.style.width = this.value + "%";
}

//Add Div
function addDiv(parent_div) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var parent = document.getElementById(parent_div);
  if (parent) {
    parent.appendChild(div);
  }
}
var button = document.getElementById("addsquare");
if (button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    // change dynamically your new div
    addDiv('parent', {
      'class': 'square'
    });
  });
}
```

```css
#parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 94.2%;
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parent>div {
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
  width: calc(50px - 2px);
  height: calc(50px - 2px);
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
}

input,
button {
  margin: 0;
}

.controls {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.controls>h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#addsquare {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.slidewrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <h2>Controls</h2>
  <button id="addsquare">Add a Square!</button>
  <div class="slidewrap">
    <input type="range" min="25" max="100" value="25" class="slider" id="range">
    <div>Game zone is set to: <span id="value"></span>%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias! I already implemented Raul's code when they answered the question but I still find your answer valuable, which is why I upvoted it. Is this considered a more optimized way of going about this situation?

Comment: No worries :)
It's not a major difference in performance (but depends on the great scope of what your building) but usually the way to go when dealing with dynamically created elements. Pros for delegation is a) you wouldn't have a bunch of `EventListener`s in your sessions.  
b) you wouldn't need to remove the `EventListener`s if your squares are removable

Comment: Thanks for the intel! This was a small pointless project but the principles are what stand. I guess I will mess around with adding a remove square button.